# counting files that DO NOT have a file extension

Tags: python

I currently have this;

```
names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(UserInput[0]+'/*.txt')]
for i in names:
        print("file found - "+i)
```

Works perfectly for counting filenames ending with .txt and obtaining the basename.

However, I have a folder with a done of filetype file. I'd like to find all of the files that do not have an extension associated with them ... I'm pretty stumped how I'd change the /*.txt part to accommodate this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over all the files, and discard the ones which have an extension.

```py
import os

for x in os.scandir(UserInput[0]):
    if '.' in x:
        continue
    print("file found -", x)
```

Comment: This worked great ... I modified is slightly to include "if os.path.isdir(i) or '.' in i:" to stop it finding directories in here too, and it's given me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`pathlib` is king.

`*` is a pattern for all files, 1 level deep. 
`**/*` is a pattern for all files in all subfolders.

```py
import pathlib

for file_ in pathlib.Path(<your path here>).glob("**/*"): # or glob("*")
   if not file_.suffix:
       print(file_)
```

Comment: +1 for pathlib: there's really no reason to mess about with strings and os.path any more, and it's amazing how many bugs that catches

Comment: The backslash here is crazy. A literal backslash would be `\\ ` but it's still wrong for non-Windows platforms (whereas Windows, in spite of all its other problems, actually allows you to use a forward slash here, which doesn't need escaping in Python).

Comment: Yes, shouldn't that be `**/*`?

Comment: Both ways work exactly the same for me, _should_ it be a forward slash? I'm using win10 however, might be different for *nix.

Comment: There is no indication that the OP actually wants to traverse arbitrary depths of subdirectories anyway.

Comment: Newer versions of Python will complain about unpaired backslashes, whereas older versions will silently (forgivingly, or erroneously, depending on your use case) interpret it as a literal backslash.